# Problemas no mapeamento com Fluent

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent-api

Já tinha uma tabela de revenda, onde tive que acrescentar um novo campo. Esse novo campo é uma FK de uma nova tabela que eu criei. Então temos: Reseller(Revenda) que recebe uma FK de Desconto. Em reseller esse campo se chama AzureDiscountGroupId(int?). O que passa é que mapeei a classe e quando eu tento abrir a tela de revenda, dá erro dizendo que não existe o campo: **AzureDiscountGroup_Id**, observe que ele tenta criar um novo campo. Entendo que isso seja devido a mapeamento errado. Vou listar abaixo as classes, sendo que reseller é muito grande, removi alguns campos(irrelevantes tê-los) e deixei apenas a PK, a FK e as virtuais para economizar espaço aqui.
Desconto

```
public class AzureDiscountGroup : EntityBase
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public decimal PercDesconto { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Reseller> Resellers { get; set; }
    }
```

A model Reseller

```
public class Reseller : EntityBase
    {       
        public virtual ICollection<WhiteLabel> WhiteLabels { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; } 

        public DateTime? AcceptContractDate { get; set; }
        public int? AcceptContractCustomerId { get; set; }
        public virtual Customer AcceptContractCustomer { get; set; }

        public int? AzureDiscountGroupId { get; set; }
        public virtual AzureDiscountGroup DiscountGroup { get; set; }
    }
```

ResellerMap

```
public class ResellerMap : CustomEntityTypeConfiguration<Reseller>
    {
        public ResellerMap()
        {
            this.ToTable("Reseller");
            this.HasKey(p => p.Id);
            this.Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

            this.Property(x => x.Name).HasMaxLength(200).IsRequired();
            this.Property(x => x.Alias).HasMaxLength(30).IsRequired();
            this.Property(x => x.Enabled).IsRequired();
            this.Property(x => x.CategoriesIds).HasMaxLength(200).IsOptional();
            this.Property(x => x.ResellerMpnId).HasMaxLength(100).IsOptional();
            this.Property(x => x.PathServiceContractAzure).HasMaxLength(700).IsOptional();
            this.Property(x => x.PathPartnershipContractAzure).HasMaxLength(700).IsOptional();

            this.HasOptional<Customer>(c => c.AcceptContractCustomer).WithMany().HasForeignKey(c => c.AcceptContractCustomerId);
            this.HasOptional<AzureDiscountGroup>(z => z.DiscountGroup).WithMany().HasForeignKey(z => z.AzureDiscountGroupId);
        }
    }
```

Map de Desconto

```
public class AzureDiscountGroupMap : CustomEntityTypeConfiguration<AzureDiscountGroup>
    {
        public AzureDiscountGroupMap()
        {   
            this.ToTable("AzureDiscountGroup");
            this.HasKey(p => p.Id);
            this.Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
            this.Property(x => x.Descricao).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
            this.Property(x => x.PercDesconto).IsRequired();
        }
    }
```

O que tenho que fazer/corrigir para funcionar corretamente?

**OBS**
Observe que no Sql Montado(output do debug) ele cria um novo Field, como podem ver

```
SELECT
.........
[Extent1].[AzureDiscountGroupId] AS [AzureDiscountGroupId], 
[Extent1].[AzureDiscountGroup_Id] AS [AzureDiscountGroup_Id], 
...........
```

No OutPut do Debug peguei essa exceção

> -- Failed in 13 ms with error: Invalid column name 'AzureDiscountGroup_Id'.
>
> Closed connection at 29/03/2019 10:13:55 -03:00
>
> Exceção gerada:
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' em
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Comment: como está a entidade do `AzureDiscountGroup`?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, você diz diretamente no banco de dados? Na classe está como postei acima e no banco normal

Comment: Faltou você mapear a o campo `AzureDiscountGroupId` então adicione uma linha a mais na sua classe de mapeamento, exemplo: `this.Property(x => x.AzureDiscountGroupId);` e as outras configurações desse campo. Porque acontece isso? porque se você não colocar é adicionado um por convenção e no seu caso dá erro.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, em realidade o WithMany() vazio é que zoou. Fiz assim: (a => a.Reseller) e aí funcionou. Não respondi ainda, porque preciso fechar algo aqui e depois eu fecho meus posts

Comment: Mas, mesmo assim o seu mapeamento continua errado...